# Can I force him to pay?

Tags: home-loan

My boyfriend and I just purchased a home together less than a year ago. Both of our names are on the mortgage and deed (that gives the living person the property rights if the other becomes deceased). He is threatening to move out.  I am not planning on moving any where. I love my home and want to stay here. His credit is excellent and he pays his bills on time. He is showing early signs of dementia but refuses to seek professional help accusing me of doing things to drive him crazy, which I have nothing to gain from.  Can I force him to pay his share of the mortgage if he moves out?

Comment: Go to mediation or get counseling. You can't force him to do anything. If he won't go with you, go alone.

Comment: This could better be answered on Legal.SE.

Comment: Why in the world would you think he should be obligated to pay for your place to live?

Answer (score 4):

Its best to seek a lawyer, but it is unlikely you can force him to pay.

You probably know couples, that are in some part of the divorce process, that have trouble obtaining court ordered payments.  In your case you have less of a legal standing (exception: if you have children together).  As far as the house goes, the two of you entered into some sort of business arrangement and it will be difficult to "force" him to pay.

One thing that works for you is that he has excellent credit.  If he is interested in keeping a high credit rating he will ensure that no payments are late on the home.  Your question suggests that the two of you are not getting along very well right now, and that needs to stop.  The best financial decision you can make right now is to get along with him.

It seems that the two of you have not officially broken up.  If you do decide to depart ways, do so as amicably as possible.  You will have to work to get the home in your name only, and him off the deed.  This benefits both of you as you will have sole control of the house and this ill advised business decision can end.  He will have the home off his credit and will not be responsible if you miss a payment and can also buy a home or whatever of his own.

Good luck and do your best to work this out.  Seeking peace will cost you a lot less money in the long run.  Fighting in court cost a lot of money.  Giving in to semi-reasonable demands are far cheaper then fighting.

Here is an example.  Lets say he normally contributes $500 to the mortgage, and he decides to move out.  I would ask him to contribute $200 until you can get his name off the loan, say 6 months at the most.  After that you will put the house up for sale if you cannot obtain a mortgage in your own name and will split any profits.